# How to resolve "The PivotTable field name is not valid" while working with Power Pivot and Data Model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have built a report using pivot table for a client and he has encountered this problem where if you simply refresh the pivot, it works fine but if you click Refresh All from the Data tab, it gives this error:

“The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.”

As per my research, the sole reason for this error is, if there are one or more columns in the source data without headers. In my case, the pivot table is based on a Data Model instead of a simple excel table or a range of data. Even then I looked at every column of Data Model tables but found nothing.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason?

Comment: Please share some screenshot so we can understand better or some link to visualize the excel file, without more specific context it is difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: Hey @DavidLeal, Thank you for your comment. I just posted the answer to my question. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Sharing here so it may help someone else. The reason why Refresh worked and Refresh All gave error was, there was no problem in my current Pivot report. It was another Pivot table on a hidden sheet whose data source has been changed. So, traced that pivot table, changed it's source and it was solved!